# C# String.CompareTo not returning the results I would expect

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I am trying to compare strings for less than etc - in a similar way I would compare numbers.

My issue is the following comparison returns true:

```
var expectThisToBeFalse = "315160".CompareTo("40000") < 0;
```

I know I can compare these as numbers, but in my application I do not know if they are numbers or letters.

Can anyone explain what I am misssing, and if there is a comparison method that would work

eg would show:

"1" is less than "2"

"a" is less than "b"

"aa" is greater than "b"

etc...

Comment: See the red note on [String.CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto) (and the remarks section). You'll need a custom comparer for this.

Comment: @Jimi I am not looking for equivalent-  I am looking for greater or less than

Comment: *The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations*. That's the part that matters. `"315160".CompareTo("40000") < 0` is true because the comparison determines that `3` comes before `4`: You could start with a basic comparison: `[string].Length` or `[string].ToCharArray().Length`. Add any other logic required to parse the array. Or `OrderBy([length]).ThenBy([value])`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not missing anything. The metod you use compares two strings alphabetically. It means that if string A is in the alphabet ahead of string B, then it returns -1.

Because you're comparing two strings, not two numbers, the function looks at the first character of both of the strings ("3" and "4" in your example. Because "3" has a lower ASCII code than "4" (51 and 52, respectively), the function concludes that "315160" is ahead **in the alphabet** than "40000", so it returns -1. Because you compared the result of this function (-1) with 0, the variable is (correctly) `true`, because -1<0.

For what you wish, you will need to program your own function. I don't know if there is any function already programmed.

Later edit: [more info on string.compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_CompareTo_System_String_).

Later edit 2: something else struck me as interesting:

> but in my application I do not know if they are numbers or letters.

For a simpler way of solving this, you may begin by checking if the two inputs are numbers or letters. You would save yourself a lot of trouble, because sometimes these two inputs will be numbers and solving is super-easy.

Comment: For this same reason, "aa" will be less than "b", not greater, because "aa" comes before "b" alphabetically.

Comment: "Lower ASCII code": Not quite correct. It performs a "culture-sensitive and case-sensitive comparison." So, nothing to do with an irrelevant character set (ASCII) and not completely respective of a UTF-16 code unit or Unicode codepoint lexicographic ordering. It uses [Unicode locale data](http://cldr.unicode.org/).